# Android resizing checkbox programmatically doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have created a `CheckBox` programmatically and gave it `WRAP_CONTENT` when adding it to the parent with `LayoutParams`. I have changed the `CheckBox` into a `ImageView` and the resize worked well. The main reason that I used `CheckBox` is for a `selector` and the two states: `checked true/false`

```
parentLayout.addView(checkBox, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Is there something I missed or done wrong?

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
mainLayout.addView(parentLayout, params);
```

Comment: where you are setting the resized image? put that code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `ButtonDrawable` on `null` and the `BackgroundDrawable` to resource worked.